# Page Level redirection for S3 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, http-redirect

I have a website (say **example.com**) that is hosted on AWS S3 (bucket name - "**xyz**") and is serving traffic via a Cloudfront distribution.  The CDN has the Origin mapped to the S3 as per usual practice to deliver the content. The DNS (Route 53) record is mapped to this CDN distribution.

I recently deleted an object from this S3 bucket, say **xyz/hello/hello-jon**
So when the users are trying to hit **example.com/hello/hello-jon**, they are getting a 404 error as expected. I'd like to redirect this to a different page that is loading from a different object in the same bucket, say, xyz/world/world-right. So that when the users try to hit the URL **example.com/hello/hello-jon** they should be redirected to **example.com/world/world-right** page.

I referred to several Amazon Docs and finally settled on this one :-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

I tried the second example **Example 2: Redirect requests for a deleted folder to a page**. The following JSON based rule was setup in the Redirection Rules of the bucket **xyz**:-

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "hello/hello-jon/"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "world/world-right/"
        }
    }
]
```

And the redirection did work, but the expected result was different. I'm getting the resultant URL as:-
http://S3-bucket-name.S3-bucket-region.amazonaws.com/world/world-right/

Instead of **https://www.example.com/world/world-right/**

Could you please help me in resolving this issue or provide an alternative that could work in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Do this changes :

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "hello/hello-jon/"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "www.example.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "world/world-right/"
        }
    }
]
```

Mentioned in document for redirect host.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Tried this. It worked for redirecting hello/hello-jon/ (that is with trailing slash), but the same fails without the slash, i.e. hello/hello-jon